# Copying data from one reference Excel workbook into another varying one

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA, and I don't have a programming background.

I am attempting to make formatting changes to an open workbook, then copy and paste data from a common, separate workbook file stored in the same directory into the open workbook, possibly without "activating" the common/reference workbook.

The file I want to copy common data from is CUSTOMER FINAL FOR INSPECTION REPORTS DW.xlsx.  The other file VIBRA PARKING LOT is the one I want to run the macro on, except this will change as I open subsequent workbooks to which I want to apply the same macro.  So the VIBRA PARKING LOT is not a static reference. (I guess I want the reference to be whatever the open, active workbook is.)

I am tempted to say that the answer involves calling the data from the reference spreadsheet WITHOUT activating it so that the macro is not having to switch activation back and forth so that it's not calling for the specific spreadsheet on which I initially programmed the macro in.  Or the answer involves somehow defining the varying spreadsheet to which I am applying the macro as whatever is open at the time while keeping the reference spreadsheet from which I am copying data constant.

I tried researching this and applying changes to the code but I couldn't get anything to work right.

Here's my code:

```
With ActiveWindow
    .Top = 255.25
    .Left = 19.75
End With
With ActiveWindow
    .Width = 1351.5
    .Height = 348
End With
Range("A1:L142").Select
Range("G44").Activate
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 8
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
Range("E6").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
Sheets("General Requirements").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Light & Ventillation").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Plumbing Facilities").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Mechanical and Electrical").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Fire Safety").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Windows("1 CUSTOMER FINAL FOR INSPECTION REPORTS DW.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
Columns("A:G").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("0171927117002 Vibra Parking Lot 020217.xlsx").Activate
Columns("A:G").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("1 CUSTOMER FINAL FOR INSPECTION REPORTS DW.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
Columns("N:N").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("0171927117002 Vibra Parking Lot 020217.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
Columns("N:N").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("P5").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: have you seen the Documentation https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate

Comment: Yes!  I was able to figure out a solution using the documentation link you provided (under "Always define and set references to all Workbooks and Sheets")  I defined the source workbook as the CUSTOMER FINAL file and the destination workbook as ActiveWorkbook and removed all the code that switched over from one to the other using .Select and .Activate.  As long as I execute the macro when I'm in the window of the spreadsheet I want to modify, I'm golden. 

Thanks!  I really appreciate it.